# Free charting tool for JavaScript that can handle 1million points

Tags: javascript, web, graphs, charts

I am looking for a free charting tool for JavaScript that can help me plot around 1 Millions Points easily and charts looks attractive. well I have tried using fallowing charts.

```
Chart.js
zing Charts
Chartist.js
PLotly.js
```

I had similar issue that when ever I try to Plot large data, my web page gets very heavy and become laggy. can some one recommend me some Good Libraries for JavaScript that can plot around 1 million to 20 million points without lagging page. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need interactive charts, or is it an option to generate it once ?

Comment: I need interactive charts because after plotting data I need to perform analysis on that chart. so ill be using zoom functionalities, each line should be in different color so data wont get mix also tooltip is essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Syncfusion JavaScript Chart library

https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-charts

Online Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/bootstrap5/chart/line.html

Documentation:https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/chart/

Syncfusion offers a free community license also.

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: this is a 30 days trail I was free forever for a university project purpose.

Comment: You can you free community license https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense Who is eligible?
Companies and individuals with less than $1 million USD in annual gross revenue and 5 or fewer developers.
Note: An entity or organization may not have ever received more than $3,000,000 USD in capital from an outside source, such as private equity or venture capital, in order to be eligible for the Community License.

Comment: I have found a page where zing chart developers helped a guy to plot around 200k points on zing chart and it work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

SciChart provides a [JavaScript Chart](https://www.scichart.com/javascript-chart-features) which can handle millions of datapoints (see [demo](https://demo.scichart.com/javascript-chart-performance-load-one-million-points)). In benchmarks SciChart.js has the [fastest performance](https://www.scichart.com/blog/scichart-is-the-fastest-js-chart-library-available-and-why-that-matters-in-todays-world/) and beats all known JavaScript Chart libraries in Big-Data test ([even LightningChart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTOznHgRLTQ))

There is a free (watermarked) community license which doesn't require a sign-up to download which you can get [here](http://scichart.com/getting-started/scichart-javascript/).

Free educational licenses (non-watermarked) are also available via an educational licensing program. More info [here](https://www.scichart.com/educational-discount-programme/)

*Disclosure: I am the owner/founder of SciChart*